# flipclock.js, change integer value on demand

Tags: jquery, flipclock

I'm using the flipclock.js.

This is my initial code:

```
            clock = new FlipClock($('.clock'), {
                clockFace: 'Counter',
                autoStart: false,
                minimumDigits: 6,
            });
```

Is it possible to set a start integer, ex. 234943, and then change later to 423345 etc. without counting one-by-one?

Answer (score 2):

To set the initial value:

```
clock = new FlipClock($('.clock'), 234943, {
                clockFace: 'Counter',
                autoStart: false,
                minimumDigits: 6,
            });
```

You can update the value with:

```
clock.setTime(423345);
```